# How to justify $\lVert \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_jh_j\rVert^2 \leq \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_j^2$ when $h_j$ are orthonormal

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We work in a Hilbert space $H$.

I want to show that a series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_jh_j$ converges where $h_j$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$. To do this, I want to show that  the tail
$$\lVert \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_jh_j\rVert \to 0$$
tends to zero. I want to know, if it is true that
$$\lVert \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_jh_j\rVert^2 \leq \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty a_j^2$$
and why is this true? I think because one writes the LHS as an inner product 
$$(\sum_j a_jh_j, \sum_k a_kh_k)$$
and then uses the orthonormality of the basis but how I can take the *infinite* sums out of that inner product when I don't know if the original series converges? What is the justification?

Comment: You seem to be working with a real Hilbert space, for otherwise you'd have to write $\sum \lvert a_j\rvert^2$. And presumably there's an assumption that $\sum a_j^2 < +\infty$. Take finite sums to see that $\sum a_k h_k$ is a Cauchy sequence, then take the limit as the upper end of the sum tends to $\infty$ - which is allowed since you've previously shown that the sum converges.

Comment: Presumably you know that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j^2$ converges to some number $A$. Thus, given an $\varepsilon>0$, $\sum_{j=n+1}^{n+p}a_j^2<\varepsilon$ for all $p$ when $n$ is large enough. Therefore
$$\left\Vert\sum_{j=n+1}^{n+p}a_jh_j\right\Vert^2<\varepsilon$$ for all $p$ when $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Cauchy criterion. If $m<n$ then
$$
\Bigl\|\sum_{k=m}^na_k\,h_k\Bigr\|^2=\sum_{k=m}^n|a_k|^2,
$$
which can be made smaller than any $\epsilon>0$ because $\sum_{k=1}^\infty|a_k|^2<\infty$. Since a Hilbert space is complete, this implies that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k\,h_k$ is convergent.